# If-then constraint with continuous variables

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, indicator-constraints

I was usually using if-then constraints with integer variables but ended up using continuous variables and got confused. I have variables $x_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, and would like to force the program: if $x_{ij}>0$, then $x_{ji}=0$, where $i,j\in\mathcal{I}$. When I use the following (in which $\mathbb{M}$ is a big number), it looks like the constraint serves to the purpose.

$$x_{ij}\geq \mathbb{M}x_{ji} \qquad \forall i,j\in\mathcal{I}.$$

However, it does a bit further than what is expected and undesired, which is $x_{ji}=0$, when $x_{ij}=0$. The symmetry of this will be conflicting. My variable essentially denotes a flow amount from node $i$ to node $j$, and I would like to ensure: if flow occurs from $i$ to $j$, it should not occur from $j$ to $i$.

Comment: Let $x_{12}=3$ and $\mathbb{M}=1000$. I would like $x_{21}=0$. My constraint will readily ensure because the r.h.s. variable can only take $x_{21}=0$ to satisfy the constraint. However, based on my constraint, I also define $x_{21}\geq \mathbb{M} x_{12}$ which conflicts with the previous. I do not see a solution by adding your constraint on top of mine because it directly creates a conflict ($x_{12} \leq \mathbb{M}x_{21}$) based on my example. Your comments?

Comment: Yes this was wrong i misread the text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Introduce a binary variable $y_{i,j}$ and linear constraints
\begin{align}
x_{i,j} &\le M y_{i,j} \tag1 \\
y_{i,j} + y_{j,i} &\le 1 \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $x_{i,j} > 0 \implies y_{i,j} = 1$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $y_{i,j} = 1 \implies y_{j,i} = 0$.
Constraint $(1)$ (with the roles of $i$ and $j$ interchanged) enforces $y_{j,i} = 0 \implies x_{j,i} = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, @RobPratt !

Comment: Glad to help.  By the way, you should use a small upper bound $M_{i,j}$ rather than an arbitrarily large $M$.

Comment: Sure, I have a tight upper bound for $x_{ij}$ that can be used as M.

Answer (score 3):

For sake of completeness: An alternative to using an additional binary variable and a big M would be to use an SOS constraint. An SOS constraint specifies a set of variables, at most one of which may be non-zero.